# Running Bluedroid on Android under valgrind

Tags: android, valgrind, android-source, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to run bluedroid under valgrind on Android 5.1
I compiled and installed valgrind from "external/valgrind"
I'm running valgrind 3.11.0
I have selinux disabled
I'm successfully starting valgrind with logwrapper:

```
setprop wrap.com.android.bluetooth "logwrapper valgrind"
```

And it starts, but fails very shortly with:

```
Zygote   setregid() failed. errno: 1
Zygote   setreuid() failed. errno: 1
libc     pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed: Operation not permitted  
libc     pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed: Operation not permitted  
bt_osi_alarm bool timer_create_internal(clockid_t, void**) unable to create timer with clock 9: Operation not permitted  
bt_osi_alarm The kernel might not have support for timer_create(CLOCK_BOOTTIME_ALARM): https://lwn.net/Articles/429925/
```

Comment: Bluetooth protocol stack source codes is in `system/bt` . Bluetooth system service is in `packages/apps/bluetooth` . codes in bluetooth system service is connected to protocol stack via JNI(Java Native Interface)

Comment: can you answer my question in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179298/how-to-enforce-android-bluetooth-protocol-stack-to-work-only-in-secure-modes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing clock type from CLOCK_BOOTTIME_ALARM to CLOCK_BOOTTIME, in alarm.cc, i'm able to successfully run bluedroid with valgring on Android.

My valgrind startup script: (vg.sh)

```
#!/system/bin/sh                                                                                                        

 PACKAGE="com.android.bluetooth"                                                                                         

 VGPARAMS='-v --error-limit=no --trace-children=yes --log-file=/sdcard/valgrind.log.%p --tool=memcheck --leak-check=no --show-reachable=no --track-origins=yes'
 export TMPDIR=/data/data/$PACKAGE                                                                                       

 /system/bin/valgrind $VGPARAMS $*
```

I boot normally, setup logwrapper with:

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.android.bluetooth "logwrapper /system/xbin/vg.sh"
```

And just kill the bluetooth process, it then restarts under valgrind.